# How do I find code for PHP builtin functions?

Tags: php, built-in

I was looking for the php class `SplDoublyLinkedList`.
I wanted to know why the list has no `current` i.e it shows NULL when you are not using `rewind`. 
But we have a valid `key` there. Current is not null if `rewind` function is used.
Is there a way to find the classes used in php.
You can test this code:

```
$spl = new \SplDoublyLinkedList;
$dataSet = array(1,2,3,4);

foreach ($dataSet as $row) {
    $spl->push($row);
}
//$spl->rewind();
echo "count: " . $spl->count() . "<br />";
echo "valid: " . ($spl->valid() ? 'true' : 'false') . "<br />";
echo "current: " . var_export($spl->current(), true) . "<br />";
echo "key: " . $spl->key() ."<br />";
```

This is the output

```
count: 4
valid: false
current: NULL
key: 0
```

Whereas if I use rewind

```
$spl = new \SplDoublyLinkedList;
$dataSet = array(1,2,3,4);

foreach ($dataSet as $row) {
    $spl->push($row);
}
$spl->rewind();
echo "count: " . $spl->count() . "<br />";
echo "valid: " . ($spl->valid() ? 'true' : 'false') . "<br />";
echo "current: " . var_export($spl->current(), true) . "<br />";
echo "key: " . $spl->key() ."<br />";
```

I get this output

```
count: 4
valid: true
current: 1
key: 0
```

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_dllist.c

Comment: Someone has voted for closing this question. Please give atleast some reason. Is this question already there?

Comment: I voted to close this because it's looking for off-site resources

Comment: @cid what about the query i raised for SplDoublyLinkedList. Does the question already exist.

Comment: I don't know how it's implemented, but it seems quite logical behaviour to me. If the PHP code has made no attempt to navigate a list, why would the underlying library second-guess and set the pointer anyway?

Comment: @BenHillier why is the valid showing as false in first case? And suppose we use `shift` function twice and just before last element we do a rewind then we get `count` as 1 but valid as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP is opensource](https://github.com/php/php-src). I don't know enough about it to know where to look, but you can look at [this search](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=SplDoublyLinkedList&unscoped_q=SplDoublyLinkedList) to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea about why we are getting NULL when we are calling the current function() in SplDoublyLinkedList.

Comment: This is my code https:// paste .ofcode.org / JCGBMQ7pWxmDzrU2QKFJHm . Remove the spaces in between.